# encoding issue sql ad php and android

Tags: php, android, sql, utf-8, character-encoding

and thanks all u guys who are really generous in publishing your knowledges for amatuers like me, i have a php  file that gets two params from an android App (with post) and puts it into a mysQl db, it worked great till now that i test it with some other languages , for example if th "message" coming from android  is PERSIAN , in db i get some unKnown characters like: "Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…" , what can i do to my php file that gets it right, from android app.. its my php code :

```
<?php



$from = $_POST['senderNum'];
$body = $_POST['message'];



if (!is_numeric($from))
{
// Invalid input
// Do nothing
exit();
}

// connect to the MYSQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***", "***");

/*
 * DB:
 * PHONE NUMBER | BODY
 * X            | X
 *
  * You can anyway add more info like sending time etc.
  */

 // run the query insert
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO sms (nm, bd) VALUES (?, ? )"))
 {
$stmt->bind_param("is", $from, $body);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// now you have in your database the sms

// close mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();


?>
```

and here is the part of code in Eclipse that sends the Data to that php:

HttpURLConnection connection;

```
                OutputStreamWriter request = null;


                     URL url = null;   

                     String response = null;         
                     String parameters = "senderNum="+senderNum+"&message="+message+"&date="+date;   

                     try
                     {
                         url = new URL("http://mysite/a/post.php");
                         connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                         connection.setDoOutput(true);
                         connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                         connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    
                         request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                         request.write(parameters);
                         request.flush();
                         request.close();            
                         String line = "";               
                         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                         {
                             sb.append(line + "\n");
                         }

                         // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
                         response = sb.toString();
                         // You can perform UI operations here

                         isr.close();
                         reader.close();

                     }
                     catch(IOException e)
                     {
                         // Error
                     }

            }
```

if there is some addition code please show me where to  put it..

thank u so much..

Comment: first of all set your charset to UTF-8 http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-set-charset.php secon look at php-my-admin and check the encodung of yur varcher and text coloumns to be utf-8-genral-ci.

Comment: thank u it worked i did lots of things , i apreciate your help bro..